# Reduces to $0$ of $S$-polynomial.

Tags: polynomials, commutative-algebra, groebner-basis, monomial-ideals

It is problem 2.17 in the book *Gröbner Bases in Commutative Algebra*, by Ene and Herzog.

> Let $f,g \in S$ such that $\textrm{in}_{<}(f)$ and $\textrm{in}_{<}(g)$ are relatively prime and let $u$ and $v$ be any monomials in $S=K[x_{1}, \dots, x_{n}]$. Then $S(uf,vg)$ reduces to $0$ with respect to $uf$ and $vg$.

I know the result that if $\textrm{in}_{<}(f)$ and $\textrm{in}_{<}(g)$ are relatively prime, then $S(f,g)$ reduces to $0$ with respect to $f$ and $g$. Also I know the partial answer when $u=v$. (It is a trivial corollary of former statement.) However, I don't know how to approach in another case. Any answer, hint or suggestion would be appreciated.

EDIT: Now I've got an answer.

> Let $f = m+f_{1}, g = w + g_{1}$ where $\textrm{in}_{<}(f) = m, \textrm{in}_{<}(g) = w$. Then, $$\textrm{lcm}(mu,wv) = mwp$$ for some monomial $p = \textrm{lcm}(u,v)$ since $\gcd(m,w) = 1$. Hence, $$uf = mu + uf_{0}, vg = wv+vg_{0}, \textrm{in}_{<}(uf) = mu, \textrm{in}_{<}(vg) = wv, \textrm{lcm}(\textrm{in}_{<}(uf),\textrm{in}_{<}(vg)) = \textrm{lcm}(mu,wv) = mwp,$$
>   hence
>   \begin{align*}S(uf,vg) &= \frac{\textrm{lcm}(\textrm{in}_{<}(uf),\textrm{in}_{<}(vg))}{mu}uf - \frac{\textrm{lcm}(\textrm{in}_{<}(uf),\textrm{in}_{<}(vg))}{wv}vg \\ 
> & = \frac{wp}{u}uf-\frac{mp}{v}vg = p(wf -mg) \\
> & = p(gf-g_{1}f - fg+f_{1}g)  =p(f_{1}g - g_{1}f).
> \end{align*}
>   Now we claim that $S(uf,vg)$ is reduces to 0 with respect to $pg, pf$. Suppose that $$\textrm{in}_{<}(pf_{1}g) = \textrm{in}_{<}(pg_{1}f).$$
>   Then, $$\textrm{in}_{<}(f_{1}g) = \textrm{in}_{<}(g_{1}f),$$
>   which gives contradiction by the argument on the proof of the proposition 2.15 in the book. So we may now assume without loss of generality that $\textrm{in}_{<}(pf_{1}g) > \textrm{in}_{<}(pg_{1}f) \implies \textrm{in}_{<}(f_{1}g) > \textrm{in}_{<}(g_{1}f).$ Then, by the lemma 2.4,
>   $$\textrm{in}_{<}(S(uf,vg)) = \textrm{in}_{<}(f_{1}pg) > \textrm{in}_{<}(g_{1}pf).$$
>   Hence, it is standard expression. Since this argument holds with respect to $uf$,   $ug$, and $vf$,$vg$, and $uf$,$vg$, our problem is solved. (Note that for $u,v$ cases, we can recall $p = lcm(u,v)$, so just rewrite it with respect to $u,v$. However, the first argument that $\textrm{in}_{<}(pf_{1}g) \neq \textrm{in}_{<}(pg_{1}f)$ holds in any representation of such terms, thus this representation only gives the rewritten second conditions, therefore it holds for any $u,v$.)

Comment: Could you explain your notation, for those who do not have that book?

Comment: @asdq Sure. First of all $\textrm{in}_{<}(f)$ is the highest monomial with respect to some term order (i.e., a total order on $\mathbb{N}^{n})$ $<$. And $S(f,g) = \frac{lcm(\textrm{in}_{<}(f),\textrm{in}_{<}(g)}{c\textrm{in}_{<}(f)}f - \frac{lcm(\textrm{in}_{<}(f),\textrm{in}_{<}(g)}{d\textrm{in}_{<}(g)} $ where $c,d$ are the leading coefficient of $f,g$ respectively, i.e., the coefficients of $\textrm{in}_{<}(f)$ in $f$ (and that of $\textrm{in}_{<}(g)$ in $g$.

Comment: Are you using that $p = \operatorname{lcm}\left(u,v\right)$? Because it isn't true in general (take $u = w$ and $v = m$).

Comment: I think you want to say $p \mid \operatorname{lcm}\left(u, v\right)$ instead of $p = \operatorname{lcm}\left(u, v\right)$. We indeed can show that $S\left(uf, vg\right) = p S\left(u, v\right)$ for some monomial $p \mid \operatorname{lcm}\left(u, v\right)$.